# How to handle 401 with spring boot with angular 8

Tags: java, angular, spring, spring-boot

I want to be able to handle 401 and show a specific page in angular 8 but currently only showing index.html file

Things to mind

1. Angular is the view for the spring boot so its not a separate application
2. I am not using spring security. Im just using filters in spring to determine if to be authorize

This is my filter.

```
@Component
public class CustomSessionFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
       protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) httpServletRequest;
        if (!req.getRequestURI().startsWith("/sample/path")){
                HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) httpServletResponse;
                httpResponse.setContentType("application/json");
                httpResponse.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Unauthorized");
                return;
            }
}
```

Maybe its relevant that i have a Controller that extend ErrorController

```
@CrossOrigin
@RestController
public class IndexController implements ErrorController {

    private static final String PATH = "/error";

    @RequestMapping(value = PATH)
    public ModelAndView saveLeadQuery() {
        return new ModelAndView("forward:/");
    }

    @Override
    public String getErrorPath() {
        return PATH;
    }
}
```

EDIT: I didnt use spring security because i dont need to login i just have to go through specific path and do some authentication.. and there is no user for the application

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to place my 0.02$ here.
In order to secure a route in your application, you can create a Security Config that extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter, where you can protect certain routes through either antMatchers or mvcMathchers (second is recommended). Furthermore, there you can declare a set of roles or conditions (via Spring Expression Language) that will automatically throw a 401 Error in case a user that does not have an access is trying to access the route.
More about that you can find here https://www.baeldung.com/security-spring

As of ErrorController, I believe that controller advice would be more suitable for this use case. It pretty much intercepts all errors that you declare and can return more informative and generic response :)
More about that https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc

As

Comment: I didnt use spring security because i dont need to login i just have to go through specific path and do some authentication.. and there is no user for the application so settings roles is not necessary. Currently going to /index.. it seems that my angular interceptor is not being called anymore.

With ControllerAdvice will check that out. Thanks!